# How to make a default variable in less like sass's !default tag

Tags: less

I have a `global.less` file which calls a `variables.less` file and then a `component.less` file.

I want to have default variables set-up inside the component file and be able to override them in the variables file.

But the component file comes after the less file so the default component variables will override the variables set in the `variables.less` file.

Is there any option in Less I can use like Sass's `!default` keyword?

Comment: See [Default Variables](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-default-variables).

Comment: @seven-phases-max as far as I can tell, using that format if I have a variable set in the variables.less file it will be overridden by the variable set in the components.less file. This means I cannot have a default variable set in the components.less file that can be overridden by resetting it in on central place - the variables.less file. Is that correct?

Comment: No, it's not. You just need to include your custom `variable.less` *after* `components.less`. That's it.

Comment: [Check out this issue on Github](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1706)

Comment: Read [this nice article](http://earthli.com/news/view_article.php?id=2965) for more novice friendly details on Less variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution as stated by @seven-phases-max is to move the variables.less file after my components file.
e.g.

Files

- global.less - main less file
- variables.less - contains all variables
- component.less - contains less code and default variables

Inside the global.less file call the two files in the following order

```
@import "component.less";
@import "variables.less";
```

Inside the component.less file you can have a default variable `@color: red` and the following css

```
body {
  background-color: @color
}
```

If you compile the previous code, the body will have a background color of red - as it has used the default variable in the component file.

Inside the variables.less file you can override the variable `@color: blue`

Now when the less files get compiled, the background color of the body tag will be blue, not red - redeclaring the variable `@color` inside the `variables.less` file overrides the default `@color` variable in the `components.less` file